# R: Adding a lines( ) function to a barplot and getting the x-values to match up

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a `barplot()` with the following code:

```
mp<-barplot(data.30.s$mean.rev,names.arg=data.30.s$dma.name, 
            main="Mean", ylab="Mean",las=2, cex.names=.5)
abline(h=mean(data.30.s$mean.rev))
lines(data.30.c$mean.rev,col=34)
```

`data.30.s` and `data30.c` have the same x-values and only differ in Y-values. I want to plot the line over the barplot to give a comparison. However, the x categories aren't matching up.

In this situation, I used identical datasets to see if the lines would work, but as you can see the plotted line x values don't match up. Any idea how to fix this or do this ggplot would be greatly appreciated. My ggplot code was:

```
ggplot(data.30.s,aes(dma.name,mean.rev))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

but the X axis names didn't work and were a garbled mess.

[image: img]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
lines(mp, data.30.c$mean.rev,col=34)
```

The reason this should work is that barplot returns the x-values at which the midpoints of bars have been drawn. Sio instead of using the index of the lines argument as you had been trying (implicitly) you will now give the right x-values to line up with the bars.